# Vector of tuple structs

Tags: c++, templates, vector

I'm getting an error on the following code snippet;

```cpp
#include <cstdio>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

struct tuple {
    int x;
    int y;
};

int main() {

    //srand(time(NULL));
    vector<tuple> locations;

    int dimentions = 20;
    double filledness = 0.65;


    while (locations.size() < dimentions * dimentions * filledness) {
        tuple point;
        point.x = rand() % dimentions;
        point.y = rand() % dimentions;

        locations.push_back(point);
    }

    int count = locations.size();
    tuple start, end;

    start = locations[rand() % count];
    end = locations[rand() % count];

    cout << count << endl;

    for (int i = 0; i < locations.size(); i++) {
        cout << locations[i].x << " " << locations[i].y << endl;
    }
    cout << start.x << start.y << endl;
    cout << end.x << end.y;

    return 0;
}
```

The vector initialization is in my main and the struct outline just above. I obviously don't understand something about vectors. I've tried making the struct a class as well as replacing vector of tuples with a vector of tuple*.

Can someone please explain why a vector can't be used in this way,

I would prefer if you didn't tell me how to fix the error directly.

```
error: template argument 1 is invalid
     vector<tuple> locations;
```

Comment: There's nothing obviously wrong with the shown code. Therefore, the problem must be in the code that's not shown. You must follow the instructions for creating a [mcve], if you want someone to help you.

Comment: In C++ a struct/class declaration requires a semi-colon ;   after. I don't see any in your code? I don't think this is your full code.

Comment: The code above is perfectly valid. Make sure you call it an `std::vector` and `#include <vector>`.

Comment: Also post the exact error.

Comment: posted the exact error

Comment: @SwimMaster Do not call your type `tuple`, and especially after you used `using namespace std;`.  There is a `std::tuple` in the C++ standard library.

Comment: You've just discovered [why `using namespace std;` is bad practice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice). Your code is confused between your `tuple` and `std::tuple`. Do yourself a big favor, and completely forget that `using namespace std;` is a part of the C++ language. Get rid of it, or perpetually run into mysterious compilation errors, like this one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason for your error is this struct:

```
struct tuple {
    int x;
    int y;
};
```

1) You called your type `tuple`, when there is a [std::tuple](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/tuple) that exists in the standard library and

2) You used `using namespace std;`, thus any mention of `tuple` in your code potentially clashes with `std::tuple`.

If you rename your struct to `my_tuple` or similar, the error that you are getting now should be remediated.

Comment: Saving because this is a perfect case on why `using namespace std;` is a terrible idea.